# How to implement Discrete time FIR Hilbert transformer filter?

Tags: filters, hilbert-transform

I want to implement FIR Hilbert transformer filter in Matlab.

Comment: What is your question? So you have designed a FIR Hilbert transformer and now you need to implement it? Then your question would be "how can I implement an FIR filter in Matlab?". Or do you need to *design* an FIR Hilbert transformer, i.e., find its coefficients?

Comment: Sir i want to know that how a filter can be designed in Matlab, if we know about its transfer function in frequency domain.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it became clear that you're actually interested in the *design* of an FIR Hilbert transformer. There are many ways to design a Hilbert transformer, but for you one of the most straightforward ways is probably to use the Matlab function [firpm.m](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/firpm.html?searchHighlight=firpm&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) with `'ftype'` set to `'h'` (for Hilbert transformer). This will design an FIR Hilbert transformer with an equiripple behavior (i.e., with the maximum approximation error being minimized). Alternatively, you could use [firls.m](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/firls.html?searchHighlight=firls&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) for a least squares design. If you use `firls.m` you need to set the filter type `'ftype'` to `'hilbert'`.

Comment: Thank you sir for your suggestion. This function is working but i want to know how to make it discrete form so that i can apply on a number of sample in Matlab .

Comment: @AbhishekShukla: The result *is* a discrete time filter, i.e., a set of FIR filter coefficients. So you can apply them to any input sequence in Matlab.

Comment: Sir I have one more doubt regarding this filter. I want to find the Hilbert transform some data sample but the size of sample is large. When I am doing filtering using this filter it is showing error. Can we design it in terms of sampling frequency ?

Comment: @AbhishekShukla: [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/37961/4298) should be helpful.

Comment: Matlab scipt of Hilbert Transformer filter :f=[.05,0.95],m=[1,1],'h=firpm(32,f,m,'hilbert'); Sir this code given Hilbert coefficient but how can I use  sampling frequency in this method. After that I want to filter random number of sample through this filter.